# Mint clone with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, clone

I have been playing with Rails 4 for last couple of months. Since I don't have any original ideas, I am practicing by building clones of famous sites like Stackoverflow, Twitter, Facebook, IMDB, Pinterest, Wordpress blog etc. I was thinking of building clone of [Mint](https://www.mint.com/). Can somebody breakdown the steps required? If you could specify gems that could be best for it, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Far, *far* too broad a question.

Comment: Ok. What else would you like to know? I haven't thought about it much. I am just brainstorming. That's why I am open to ideas. If you were to built a Mint clone, how would you start?

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question SO is designed for. You might have better luck on programmers.stackexchange.com, but I'm not sure. I'd consider taking a step back and trying to implement something significantly smaller in scope, a la railstutorial.org.

Answer (score 1):

The initial challenge is retrieving the data from your users' financial institutions.  Unless you're just going to support a couple of banks, that will be a very large effort for one person to implement and maintain.

Yodlee has [APIs](http://www.yodlee.com/platform-solutions/product-solutions/apis/) to do just this for you.  As a matter of fact, Mint used to use Yodlee.  I found one gem for Yodlee's API but it doesn't look to be actively maintained.  You can also check out David Lesches's [five part series on Rails and Yodlee](http://davidlesches.com/blog/yodlee-and-rails-implementation-part-1-getting-started).

Once you've got the transactional data you'll have to categorize each transaction, which is the core of the value Mint brings.  You'll have to look at the data you get back from Yodlee to figure out the best way to do this.